# Cannot insert data in virtual table (HIVE) from SAP HANA

Tags: hadoop, hive, hana

I have a Hive table (visible from HBase) in a Hadoop system and ODBC from Hortonworks installed in SAP HANA server. Then, I Have a SAP HANA Studio Remote Source from where I can see the Hive tables. The Remote Source definition appears in the following image:

[image]

The DML Mode is "readwrite"

I create a `bicing_test` virtual table. Then, I can to run Select queries to this virtual table, but cannot run Insert/Update Queries:

[image: enter image description]

The log error is de following:

> Could not execute 'insert into "BICING_USER"."HIVE_bicing_test" values (3)' SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: datasource doesn't support insert statement: line 1 col 27 (at pos 26)

Is it possible to run Insert queries in a virtual table?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is not a general limitation of virtual tables via SDI or SDA but a property of the specific adapter. For SDI the properties are documented in [EIM SDI/SDQ Admin Guide](http://help-legacy.sap.com/download/multimedia/hana_options_eim/SAP_HANA_EIM_Administration_Guide_en.pdf). There it says for the SDI-HIVE Adapter "... INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE functions are more
complicated than with “standard” SQL, and therefore they are not supported in this first version of the Hive Adapter...". So I guess the SDA Adapter has the same limitation, even though I do not know where the properties of the SDA Adapters are documentet systematically (is there any places at all???).

Some adapters, e.g. the HANA Adapters (for accessing other HANA Systems), the SDI DB2 Logreader Adapter etc. support insert/update/delete into virtual tables. You have to check for the specific adapter you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I was thinking it was problem of the driver configuration installed in SAP HANA.